# jQuery dialog/serialize conflict?

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, dialog

I have run into an issue where an input field within a form I'm using should only be shown under certain conditions.  I chose to display it with jQuery's `dialog()` method.  However, after the `dialog()` method is called, any subsequent calls to jQuery's `serialize()` method will leave out that input field from the generated string.  I suspect that this is somehow due to `dialog()` removing the element from the form or something along those lines, but I can't seem to find a fix.

Here is the HTML and JS to reproduce the issue:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form">
    <div id="dialog" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" />
    </div>
    <!-- Other form inputs here -->
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
alert($('#form').serialize()); // "foo=bar"
$('#dialog').dialog({
    buttons: {
        OK: function() {
            alert($('#form').serialize()); // Should be "foo=bar", but is "" instead?
            $(this).dialog('close');
            alert($('#form').serialize()); // Still "".
            setTimeout(function() {
                alert($('#form').serialize()); // Still "".
            }, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

There are several other inputs within the form that should not be shown on the dialog, so putting the `form` tags within the dialog `div` is not an option for me.

Comment: Tried something like `var myForm = $('#form').serialize();` and then use it inside `OK` ?

Comment: @dotoree: If I did that, then the new value of the input would not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NicolaPeluchetti offered one possible solution, but I found this one to be less of a hassle:

In the `dialog()` call options, I added the following:

```
close: function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#form');
}
```

Basically, it sticks `#dialog` back into `#form` when the dialog is closed.  This won't help if you need the input to be part of the form *while the dialog is open*, but in my case, I only needed it to be available after the dialog was closed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is because the dialog alter the markup, for it to work inlude the form tag in the dialog

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none;">
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" />
    </form>
</div>
```

EDIT - if you can't put the form tag you will have to use hidden fields and keep those in sync with jquery, i'm afraid

```
<form id="form">
    <div id="dialog" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" name="foo_dialog" class='dialog' value="bar" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="" />
    <!-- Other form inputs here -->
</form>
```

js

```
$('input.dialog').keyup(function(){
    var name = this.name.replace('_dialog', '');
    $('input:hidden[name='+name+']').val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't include the form tag in the dialog, as it contains a whole lot of other fields that shouldn't be shown on it.  I'll add this to my question; sorry for leaving it out.

Comment: Nicola, So in clearer terms, what you're saying is that because #form is outside of #dialog in the markup, the $('#dialog') object can't reference the $('#form') object, correct?

Comment: @AdamHoke i was saying that by creating the dialog the elements inside  itare inserted in the new markup and detached from the original position, i used forms inside dialogs but the whole form was inside, i'm not sure that you can have only a field inside a dialog

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti:  If that's the case, I might need to consider creating a separate form, and `serialize()`ing and merging both of them.

Comment: @drrcknlsn i think you will have to do some tricks with hidden fields i'm afraid, i updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem, when i was filling a dialog with Ajax-loaded `form` content and serializing it.

The `form` was serialized like this:

```
var form = $('#encuesta').serialize();
function genera() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "genera_encuesta.php",
        data: form,
        success: function(datos) {
        $('#res1').html(datos);
        }
    });

}
```

I solved it by doing:

```
function genera() {
    var form = $('#encuesta').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "genera_encuesta.php",
        data: form,
        success: function(datos) {
             $('#res1').html(datos);
        }
    });     
}
```

....

Hope it helps somebody ton dont waste a lot of time.